# Create elevated console/cmdline app windows - suggestions?

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, admin, uac

Looking for suggestions on how to go about the following, i.e what would be the best language to do it in etc, third party tools are a no :(

I've been tasked to create some sort of windows shell/command line interface that will allow a standard users to install a specific set of applications (configurable by administrators) (installation requires Admin/UAC elevation) due to security restrictions the user cannot have elevated privileges so they'll be able to run the shell as a standard user and it would have hidden/encrypted credentials built in to run the installs as.

Some of the requirements are as follows:

1. It would need to work on Server 2008 R2, 2012 r1 and 2012 r2
2. The credentials used to perform the install would have to be hidden (encrypted) from the end user.
3. Ideally  it could work  by us providing some config to it prior to handing that server over to the customer and limit what it could be used to install to a particular .exe or .msi  (so we know of a need to install an app, we are advised of the name of the install and can logon and can enter it into a form maybe so only that app can be installed, then hand the server over to the customer who runs the same utility or shell extension or  whatever and can then install their app.
4. Even more ideally it was more intelligent than that and some means of ensuring any .msi was indeed installing the application that the msi name related to (seems unlikely but just in case a normal user created an .msi to grant himself further admin access as per http://blogs.technet.com/b/fdcc/archive/2011/01/25/alwaysinstallelevated-is-equivalent-to-granting-administrative-rights.aspx )
5. Ideally its lifespan would be limited in terms of time (unsure if this could be for example to x number of days).

Any pointers on how to go about this, seems like a good challenge :)

Thanks for reading all that!
Mike

Comment: You cannot acquire UAC elevation with "hidden credentials".  Going through the UAC prompt is a rock-hard requirement.  The only way ahead is to put the code that requires the elevation in a service that runs with a system account.  That requires a single elevation, when the service is registered.

Comment: Does this apply to RunAs?

Comment: The runas.exe program runs an executable as a different user. That is not the same thing as elevation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the responses,

I managed to do this in C#, with no prior experience in the language :)

[image: Screenshot]

The application has 2 parts to it, a GUI and a service. It works by having the application send an install command via IPC to it's counterpart elevated service. (Thanks **Hans Passant** for pointing me in the right direction there).  The service initiates the installer under it's own elevated account but displays the installer GUI on the users session. Files are HMACSHA1 checksum validated prior to install, on both the app and the service.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

If a user requires the ability to install application in the `Program Files` folder, then instruct the domain administrator to give **Full Control** of the **Program Files** folder to **Everyone**:

[image]

Just because the default setting forbids standard users from modifying programs, doesn't mean you have to keep it that way. Windows is a secure operating system that gives you the *capability* to keep it secure.

If your administrator only wants some users to be able to modify the contents of the **Program Files** folder, then only give that permission to certain users.

The better solution is to re-design the applications so that they do not install in a (by default) protected location. Have them instead install in:

```
%APPDATA_LOCAL%\Contoso\Frobber\Grob.exe
```

e.g.

```
D:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local\Contoso\Frobber\Grob.exe
```

A user is always allowed to write anything in their own profile folder.

Comment: Thanks Ian for this response, unfortunately the requirements were to have no modifications of system permissions, and the majority of the installers would be Third Party, so unable to modify install paths. I went with the creating an app approach, see my answer below. Thanks again for taking the time to respond :)